# What does "ending statements with semicolon is optional in JavaScript" mean?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript. What does this mean, exactly?

> You might see examples without semicolons.  Ending statements with
>   semicolon is optional in JavaScript.
>
> <sub>From http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_statements.asp</sub>

Comment: http://w3fools.com  You should learn from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: It is optional but a good idea to do so

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript

Comment: [optional](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/optional): available as a choice but not required. It means you can choose whether to do it.

Comment: ["The moral of this story: ASI is (formally speaking) a syntactic error correction procedure."](https://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses a C-like syntax which requires the use of semicolons to delimit certain statements. JavaScript attempts to make those semicolons optional with a semicolon insertion mechanism. This is dangerous because it can mask errors.

Like C, JavaScript has ++ and -- and ( operators which can be prefixes or suffixes. The disambiguation is done by the semicolon.

In JavaScript, a linefeed can be whitespace or it can act as a semicolon. This replaces one ambiguity with another.

via- http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

Answer (score 1):

As per the ECMAScript® Language Specification's [Automatic Semicolon Insertion section,](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9)

> **Certain ECMAScript statements (empty statement, variable statement,
>   expression statement, do-while statement, continue statement, break
>   statement, return statement, and throw statement) must be terminated
>   with semicolons. Such semicolons may always appear explicitly in the
>   source text.** For convenience, however, such semicolons may be omitted
>   from the source text in certain situations. These situations are
>   described by saying that semicolons are automatically inserted into
>   the source code token stream in those situations.

Hope this directly answers your question.

**Suggestion:** But use your best judgement and add the semi-colon yourself whenever possible.